# JSS Layout Service and Personalization

Tags: personalization, jss

When using the JSS Layout Service with my Angular application, I notice that if I add personalized content to my component, the response (and display) I get back from the Layout service depends on a certain flag. [{**pageEditing: true**, site: {name: "portal.local"}, pageState: "normal", language: "en"}]

If this value is false, my personalization seems to work.   If true, it shows some generic HTML content (code).  I notice I can control this flag by logging out of the Sitecore instance.

Is there a programmatic way to always request the pageEditing=false version from my app?   I understand that the experience editor needs to show the content so it needs to handle both.  Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

This behavior is due to being logged into Sitecore and browsing your JSS app in the same browser instance (even if they're separate tabs they share cookies).

I would suggest browsing to your app in an incognito window or separate browser.

Related question: [Layout API returning strange code into placeholder](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/12812/layout-api-returning-strange-code-into-placeholder)

Comment: Perfect...company policies do not allow incognito windows but a separate Edge browser did the trick.  Thanks for the extremely quick response Adam!